# Postgres sql to retrieve data based on aggregation and bool_or()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have User to Role table with Many to Many relation. I need to retrieve all the roles which are not privileged(false) to any VIP users or it should be Privileged only to VIP users.

[image]

I came up with a query using aggregation and bool_or() but my result set has opt4 role. opt4 role should be ignored since its Privileged to a non- vip user (user2 - line item 6)

```
select
    r.rolename
from
    pam."role" r
join pam.user_role ur on
    r.id = ur.role_id
join pam.user u on
    ur.user_id = u.id
group by
    r.rolename,
    u.vip_flag
having
     (not bool_or(ur.privileged)) or u.vip_flag=true;
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply have to add it to the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING ((not bool_or(ur.privileged)) OR u.vip_flag=true)
       AND rolename <> 'opt4'
```